# Выравнивание секций по вертикали при прокрутке

Tags: animate

Прошу помощи у знатоков, вот пример сайта http://blackhouse.uk.com/chester
эта страница поделена на 4 секции, там есть такой эффект, когда прокручиваешь страницу не до конца следующей секции, то страница автоматически докручиваеться, таким образом центрируется содержание. Я не силен в скриптах, поэтому не могу определить что это за скрипт, к примеру есть такой код`

```
<section id="cont">
<section id="cont1">
<ul id="cont2" class="spsek">
<li id="st1" class="str1 full-height vertical-center-content">
<div class="slide-inner">
содержание страницы
</div>
</li>
<li id="st2" class="full-height vertical-center-content">
<div class="slide-inner">
содержание страницы
</div>
</li>
<li id="st3" class="full-height vertical-center-content">
<div class="slide-inner">
содержание страницы
</div>
</li>
<li id="st4" class="full-height vertical-center-content">
<div class="slide-inner">
содержание страницы
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</section>
</section>
```

Каждая секция имеет высоту 100%, это я сделал скриптом

```
    function setHeiHeight() {
    $('.full-height').css({
        height: $(window).height() + 'px'
    });
}
setHeiHeight(); // устанавливаем высоту окна при первой загрузке страницы
$(window).resize( setHeiHeight ); // обновляем при изменении размеров окна
```

**подскажите скрипт для этого эффекта?**

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял за этот эффект отвечает эта функция:

```
$(window).on('scroll orientationchange touchmove', $.debounce(1000, function(){
            scroll_position = $(window).scrollTop();
            snap_range = 256;   
            $('#slides > li').each(function(){
                slide_top = $(this).offset().top;
                snap_from = Math.round(slide_top - (snap_range/2), 2);
                snap_to = Math.round(slide_top + (snap_range/2), 2);        
                if( scroll_position >= snap_from && scroll_position <= snap_to ) {          
                    snap_offset = 0; //e.g. menu bar height
                    scroll_to = $(this).offset().top - snap_offset;
                    scroll_diff = scroll_position - scroll_to;
                    if(scroll_diff != "-1")
                    {
                        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: scroll_to}, 300, 'linear');    
                    }
                }
            });
        }));
```

Работает он совместно с **jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js**

Comment: Спасибо, действительно работает